# Window regulator part build quality

Tags: power-windows, oldsmobile, reliability, alero

[Olds Alero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldsmobile_Alero) '03 has a broken left front window regulator.  The window motor's OK.

This would make it the third time this part failed; different shops did both repairs, and I'm wondering if poor quality replacement parts may not have played a role, *i.e.* an OEM using a plastic that oxidizes and becomes brittle.

Online vendors offer several brands of regulators, (*Delco*, *Dorman*, *Cardone*, *ReplaceXL*, [etc.](http://www.carparts.com/oldsmobile/alero/window-regulator)), at varying prices.  I don't know which, if any, is better, or which if any has better odds on being better.

**Non subjective questions:**

1. Without considering price, are there any *objective* parts build quality reputation brand rankings out there?
2. What exists in the way of:

   - publicly available analytical data on brand quality, (i.e. strength of materials, MTBFs, etc.), arrived at by reproducible testing with rigorous controls,
   - or statistical sales data on rate of returns by brand,
   - or customer polling of satisfaction by brand.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You do realize the premise of this question is opinion-based, right?

Comment: You have answered your own question "I know which, if any, is better."

Comment: Just wondering if the parts broke because of low quality or if there is something else causing premature failure; like improper installation, binding window track, twisted door, moisture in the door, etc.

Comment: @SolarMike, Sorry that's a typo made while editing.  Should have been "_I **don't** know..._".   The Q. is now corrected.

Comment: @CharlieRB, That's possible, but for the sake of this Q. please ignore those factors.  (Some of those factors might make interesting separate Qs.)

Comment: That is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Even if such a ranking does exist it would be of little practical use*

---

Consider the following:

- ***variations during manufacturing***

  Due to things like different suppliers for the same part, different operators, different norms adopted in different factories/assembly locations...
- ***variations during operation***

  Due to variations in temperature and humidity, the frequency of usage, the torque supplied by the motor, the loading conditions it is subjected to...
- ***variations in testing procedure***

  Just because a part is tested and certified under certain conditions, it is not a guarantee for how it will perform in the real world. The discrepancy between quoted MPG ratings and real-world MPG figures are a classic example of this.

The crux of this answer can be summed up as follows: *your mileage may vary*.

Comment: Manufacturing seems like the most interesting variable, since failures of operation and testing are all more likely given poor build quality.  If *Brand X* consistently cuts more corners more than *Brand Y*, (even if on a given month *Brand Y* makes a worse dud than *Brand X*), the odds are in favor of *Brand Y* being the safer buy of the two.